# API to identify people from photos

Tags: api, image-processing, face-recognition

I am looking for an API that can help me identify a person from a photo and then compare if it's the same or different person in any other photo.

It's kind of like how Google Photos or Facebook knows who the person could be from the photos.

Any suggests?

I looked at Cloud vision API by Google, which can only detect faces. But it doesn't let me assign it to a user and match against future images.

Answer (score 2):

[OpenCV](https://opencv.org/) is a Google Sponsored library which includes a series of features for image processing and object identification.

[TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/) is another Machine Learning stack capable of this, but requires some training.